# how to bind background color in repeater control in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

The colour is highlighted for the row from which I click delete button , but colour of other row goes after post back.

```
protected void rptLine_ItemCommand(object source, RepeaterCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (newRow != null) 
    {

        if (auditLine.Is_HCPCS_CPT_Deleted == true)
        {
            newRow.BgColor = "#FFFFFF";
            auditLine.Is_HCPCS_CPT_Deleted = false;
        }
        else
        {
            if (ddlDocument.SelectedIndex == 0 || 
                ddlReason.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, 
                    this.GetType(), "error", 
                    "alert('Document and Reason are mandatory for primary Diagnosis code.');", true);
            }
            else
            {
                auditLine.Is_HCPCS_CPT_Deleted = true;
                newRow.BgColor = "#FF7256";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how are you applying back ground color to other rows ? can you post the code

Comment: @Krishna I have already post the code.I am applying the background colour in the Itemcommand .

Comment: You said color of other rows goes after post back, how are you applying background to those rows?